# JavaScript code conventions - variable declaration

Tags: javascript, variables, syntax, coding-style

What's the less error prone approach to declare variables in JavaScript?

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
```

or

```
var a,
    b,
    c;
```

jQuery and Dojo use the second approach and personally that's my favorite in terms of code legibility, the problem is that I find it harder to debug.

Example 1:

```
var a,
    b,
    c; // oops.. semicolon instead of comma
    d,
    e;
```

Example 2:

When searching for a certain variable in the project, `var` stands out better that the variable is being declared.

**EDIT**: The original examples were wrong, i've made a mistake when copying and pasting. The code is already updated, sorry for the incovenient.

Comment: Did you mean to use semicolons instead of commas? That throws undefined variable errors in Safari.

Comment: @JeffreySweeney were you running the code with an error? the commas work fine.

Comment: @david Commas do, but semicolons will not.

Comment: The answer to this question is subjective. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: @amnotiam are you sure the answer to *which approach is more error prone* is subjective? I can't find any reason why multiple declarations would be error prone at all. Combined declarations seem to be objectively more error prone.

Comment: @GGG: Fair enough, though much of the question seems to deal with style preferences, and the question seems to answer itself with respect to potential errors.

Comment: @amnotiam agreed, it does seem to answer itself, and might be NARQ for that reason...

Comment: @ Amnotiam I'm not responding myself just because I pointed out more advantages on a given approach. The problem is that both have advantages and disavantages.

Comment: *"...both have advantages and disavantages..."* Yes, I agree. That's why I called it subjective. What one person sees as an important motivating factor, another may not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple variable declarations (rather than combined) are less error prone, for the reasons you mentioned. However, combined declarations have some other advantages:

- JSLint and possibly other linters will complain about multiple `var` keywords per scope.
- A single `var` keyword minifies better than many, for obvious reasons.
- Combining declarations forces you to declare the variables in one place, probably close to the beginning of the function they reside in, which is considered good practice.

On the flipside, as you mentioned mistakes can be made with combined variable declarations, and they can be awkwardly represented in a diff.

As long as you keep a consistent style of variable declaration throughout the project, the style you choose should not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer your second approach of using just one `var` keyword.  Recently I have taken it a step further and instantiate types onto each variable to help me prevent unintended type recasting later.  An example is:

```
var a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = {},
    d = [],
    f = "";
```

I supply an actual value here if I have a value to supply at this point.  If not I supply the following dummy values:

- `0` for number types
- `[]` for array
- `{}` for object literal and DOM nodes
- `""` for string
- `function () {return;}` for functions
- `false` for boolean
- for this purpose I don't worry about pre-assigning types for Math, Date, or RegExp types.

Comment: That seems to be a great solution that also prevents weakly typed related bugs.

Comment: My primary motivation is performance.  The latest interpreters prefer strict typing, and so I had to change my behavior and style to accommodate this new unofficial requirement of professional quality coding.

Comment: Why `function() {return;}`? `function() {}` would do the same thing.

Comment: Good to know that this can apparently improve performance. On the other hand it is often useful (including in debugging) to be able to tell whether or not a variable has been defined, which is not possible if you assign it a value at the outset.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
```

is the better approach because it will not throw undefined error. Also variables will be scoped properly & not in global scope.

```
var a=10;
    b=5;
```

would result b in global scope.

EDIT: This was in context with the sample posted originally https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9746359/2. With the updated Context, it comes down to more of individual preference. My recommendation will be to give no room for those kind of mistakes as its hard to find them.

Comment: "variables will be scoped properly & not in global scope."  What???  Variables are hoisted to the top of the scope their in, but function() { var a, b, c; } still has the variables scoped as in the function.

Comment: @Ramesh Yeah ... not so much. The only time a variable automatically ends up in the global scope is when it's not declared. He's asking about equivalent styles for declaring a variable--neither necessarily puts variables in the global scope.

Comment: A small mistake when assigning like var a=10;b=15; would result in b getting in global scope. His question initially had var a;b,c;

Comment: @Corbin I think he's referring to the accidental `;` instead of `,` forcing the next variable into the global scope (because it has no `var` keyword).

Comment: Ah yes, with his mistaken ; instead of , in the first example, it would result in a global.  Was about to say question should be edited, but looks like it already has been :).  Also, for what it's worth, the -1 isn't mine.

Comment: It would only result in a global if you also assigned. Otherwise it just throws an undefined variable error

Comment: Yes @David. As I said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746359/javascript-variable-declaration-code-conventions/9746389#comment12397417_9746389

Answer (score 0):

The second option is better in my book, as it's less redundant. Modern browsers and IDEs make it pretty easy to find a bug like you called out.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/VH7rB/) that shows what happens. Accidentally inserting a semicolon in the series causes an `Uncaught ReferenceError`. It's a quick fix and a small tradeoff for a nicer syntax. If this is the worst bug you have to deal with when writing JavaScript, you're having a great day.

Ironically, you had a typo in your second example--semicolon after `a`. Whoops. :)

EDIT: Original poster fixed typo; I'm leaving the mention in because it's relevant to the original question.

Comment: Mistakes like the one he made makes, first option better :)

Comment: @Josh Earl I've already fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is one bonus to having the multiple declaration of a variable using 1 var.

You get to have lower minified script.  Obviously the 4 bytes required to have a `var` declaration does not make much of a difference until your a place like stackoverflow.com.  Millions upon millions of download == gigs of transfer just based on a few extra `var` declarations.

Comment: A good minifier like UglifyJS will automatically squash sequential var statements into one, rendering that point moot